# Using DBCollection.mapReduce to change MongoDB schema: spurious nested "value" attribute

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I need to create a database patch that updates all elements of a MongoDB collection to a new format.
For example, grossly simplified, the old format has documents like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("572a7f30200cd11355083cd9"),
  "_class" : "Domain",
  "oldAttribute": 123
}
```

And the new format requires documents like that:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("572a7f30200cd11355083cd9"),
  "_class" : "Domain",
  "newAttribute": 123
}
```

I'm using MongoDB's Java API, and the database patches have to be written in Java as well, but rather than writing a bunch of Java code that modifies documents by first reading them and then writing them back, I figured that I could leverage `DBCollection.mapReduce()` with `MapReduceCommand.OutputType.REPLACE` to do the same thing with a small piece of JavaScript directly inside MongoDB, like so:

```
myCollection.mapReduce(map, reduce, "myCollection", MapReduceCommand.OutputType.REPLACE, null);
```

For the `map` function, I pass something like:

```
function () {
  var copy = {'_id': this._id, '_class': this._class, newAttribute: this.oldAttribute};
  emit(this._id, copy);
}
```

The `reduce` function should technically never be called as the keys are unique, so I just pass a dummy function there.

This seems to work, but there is one problem: after the map-reduce was applied, all documents in the collection now have a nested `value` attribute:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "56c2371a200cd11088252111"},
  "value":
  {
    "_id": { "$oid" : "56c2371a200cd11088252111"},
    "_class": "Domain",
    "newAttribute": 123.0
  }
}
```

(this output is pasted from the Java console, so formatting is a little different)

My question, in short, is: how can I get rid of the nested `value` attribute and have all attributes (including `_id`) at the top level?

Comment: why would you need mapReduce, why not just use update with $rename modifier?

Comment: as I said in my original question, it's grossly simplified; I'm not actually just renaming a field; the patch modifies the entire structure of a document, i.e., fields get moved around, etc.

Comment: You can use aggregation with $out then. Still no need for MapReduce which is much slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify documents in place, you can use update with [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) modifier.  Running update with [`multi:true`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) will update every document in the collection.

If you want the change to appear "atomic" and the collection is not sharded, you can use `aggregate` with [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) and this pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    {$project:{_class:1, newAttribute:"$oldAttribute"}}, 
    {$out:"collection"}
])
```

Providing the same name to `$out` as the name of the original collection will replace the collection with the newly transformed version of it.

If you want to create the new version of the collection without getting rid of the old version, then just give a new collection name to `$out`.